# How can I enable multiple selections from list when using Aurelia repeat.for?

Tags: aurelia

I have a view that allows the user to view a list of items and select a single item which in turn enables some buttons, like so:

**view-model**

```
export class ListViewCustomElement{
   @bindable rows= []

   selectedRow= null

   deleteRow() {
     let event = new CustomEvent('delete-row',{
       item: selectedItem,
       bubbles: true
     }

     this.element.dispatchEvent(event)
}
```

**view**

```
<!-- delete button enabled when user selected -->
<i class="button fa fa-times" if.bind="selectedRow" click.delegate="deleteRow()"></i>

<div repeat.for="row of rows" click.delegate="selectedRow = row">
    <i class="fa ${selectedRow == row ? 'fa-check-circle' : 'fa-check-circle-o'}"></i>
    ${row.item1} ${row.item2}
</div>
```

**parentview**

```
<list-view rows.bind="users" delete-item.delegate="deleteUser($event)"></list-view>
```

Now I need to allow multiple users to be selected.  I still need the icon for each row to show selected if that user has been selected.  Also, my `deleteRow()` function will need to pass a list of selectedRows in the event as opposed to just the single user.

**The easiest thing would be to actually add a select property to each row element, but I can't do that as it dirties my data objects.**

**ATTEMPT 1**

**view-model**

```
//added to the above vm
selectedRows = []

selectClick(indexRef){
    let index = this.selectedRows.indexOf(indexRef)
    if(index < 0){
       this.selectedRows.push(indexRef)
    }
    else{
       this.selectedRows.splice(index,1)
    }
}
```

**view**

```
<!--Changed to call new function -->
<div ... click.delegate="selectClick($index)">
    <i class="fa ${selectedRows.indexOf($index) < 0 ? 'fa-check-circle-o' : 'fa-circle-check'}"></i>
```

This all works except the icon in the view -- the indexOf doesn't get evaluated as items are added and removed from selectedRows

**ATTEMPT 2**

**view**

```
<div ref="rowItems">
   <div ref="rowItems[$index].unselected" repeat.for="row of rows" 
       click.delegate="rowItems[$index].unselected = !rowItems[$index].unselected">
      <i class="fa ${rowItems[$index].unselected ? 'fa-check-circle-o' : 'fa-check-circle'}"></i>
```

However, this approach makes it difficult to enable/disable the delete button and also causes an issue when the parentview actually deletes the selected records because the view updates but the unselected flag of the `rowItems` property does not get reset.

Any ideas on the best way to accomplish what I'm after?

Comment: why not "dirty" up the data with `isSelected`? is a *selected* state of an item not real data?

Comment: No, isSelected isn't data -- its a UI concern.  when the data object is returned to the server we don't want UI state (especially something like selected as that can change user to user, etc) stored in the DB.  The other issue is that this is a re-usable custom element that works on different data objects.  There is no guarantee that there won't be a data object that has its own isSelected property that may not be related to the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I finally solved this.

**viewmodel**

```
import {BindingEngine} from 'aurelia-binding'
@inject(Element,BindingEngine)

...

selectedItems = {}
selectedItemsCount = 0   //used to enable/disable buttons

constructor(element,bindingEngine){
    this.element = element
    this.bindingEngine = bindingEngine

    this.psub = this.bindingEngine
       .propertyObserver(this,"rows")
       .subscribe((data) => {
            if(this.asub) this.asub.dispose();

            if(!Array.isArray(data)) return;

            this.asub = this.bindingEngine
              .collectionObserver(this.rows)
              .subscribe(changes => {
                  if(changes[0].removed.length){
                      for(let item in this.selectedItems){
                          if(!this.rows.find(v => {return v.id == item})){
                             this.selectedItemsCount -= (this.selectedItems[item] ? 1 : 0)
                             delete this.selectedItems[item]
                          }
                      }
                  }
              })
        })
}    

selectClick(id){
    this.selectedItems[id] = !this.selectedItems[id]

    let total = 0
    for(let item in this.selectedItems){
       total += this.selectedItems[item] ? 1 : 0
    }

    this.selectedItemsCount = total
}

deleteRow(item){
   let responseItem = null
   if(!item){
       responseItem = []
       responseItem = this.rows.filter(v => {return this.selectedItems[v.id]})
   }
   else responseItem = item;

   let event = new CustomEvent('delete-row',{
      detail: {item: responseItem, isList: Array.isArray(responseItem)},
      bubbles: true
   })

   this.element.dispatchEvent(event)
}
```

First, the actually selecting code is similar to what peinearydevelopment suggested -- so thank for getting me headed in the right direction.  However, I needed the "global" delete button (outside the list) to be enabled/disabled when items were selected or deselected.  This is the purpose of the selectedItemsCount update in the selectClick function.

However, the bigger issue is that if I selected 5 items and clicked delete, the parent view (that owns the list of rows) is responsible for deciding if the rows should be deleted and actually removing them.  When this happened, my rows were updated, but my selectedItemsCount was not.  This was also true if an item was added to the list.

So, this it the purpose of the property and collection observer code in the constructor.  It ensures that anytime items are added to or removed from the collection, the `selectedItems` list is cleaned up and the `selectedItemsCount` is adjusted.

NOTE: The propertyObserver code probably wouldn't be necessary in many cases but in my case, the rows weren't always loaded by the time the constructor was called -- nor by the time the view was attached -- and the data loader didn't push new data into the existing array but rather replaced it.  The replace killed the array to which my collectionObserver was attached, so it was necessary to watch for that and attach a new collectionObserver.

**view**

```
<!-- delete button enabled when user selected -->
<i class="button fa fa-times" if.bind="selectedItemsCount" click.delegate="deleteRow()"></i>

<div repeat.for="row of rows">
    <i class="fa ${selectedItems[row.id] ? 'fa-check-circle' : 'fa-check-circle-o'}"></i>
${row.item1} ${row.item2}
</div>
```

I'm sure the Aurelia team would have a much more elegant way of handling all this; but hopefully this helps someone else as well.

Again, thanks to peinearydevelopment and Eliran for their input.  I agree with you both that adding an isSelected flag to each row would have been a **much** simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something from your question, but I would think you would just want something like this:

```
<div repeat.for="row of rows" click.delegate="row.isSelected = !row.isSelected">
    <i class="fa ${row.isSelected ? 'fa-check-circle' : 'fa-check-circle-o'}"></i>
    ${row.item1} ${row.item2}
</div>
```

If the row object doesn't have an `isSelected` property, then initially it will resolve to `undefined` which is falsey. Once a user clicks on it once, the `!` will coerce it to a bool value of true and further clicks will toggle that boolean value.

I assume you will want to do something with the selections at a later point in your class. Then you could use javascript's array filter function to get all selected items:

```
var selectedRows = rows.filter(function(row) { return row.isSelected; });
```

---

**UPDATE**:
Sorry that I misread your constraints before. I do agree with [Eliran Malka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547020/eliran-malka) though. I would think the general approach in scenarios such as these would be that one would receive their data from service into their viewmodel and then that data would be manipulated into view specific objects that would get bound to the view. If some of the data in those objects would need to be saved, then there would be something that would take those view objects and transform them back into the service object. Therefore the `isSelected` property wouldn't be make your data 'dirty'.

That being said, depending on what and why you need to track these changes, there are a few different options, ranging in complexity.

The easiest that I can see with the information you've provided would be similar to the first approach. Please let me know if this doesn't suffice and we could try another option.

**view**

```
<div repeat.for="row of rows" click.delegate="selectedIndices[$index] = !selectedIndices[$index]">
    <i class="fa ${${selectedIndices[$index] ? 'fa-check-circle' : 'fa-check-circle-o'}"></i>
    ${row.item1} ${row.item2}
</div>
```

**viewmodel**

```
selectedIndices = {}
```

Comment: Yes, that would be the easy way.  However, I cannot add isSelected to my data objects.  Doing what you've suggested actually changes the structure of my data object by adding a new property.

Comment: Correct, sorry, maybe I missed it, but I didn't see where in your question you stated that you couldn't do that.

Comment: NP, I've bolded it to help make that restriction a bit more visible -- its there, just kind of hard to find in all the other text.

Comment: If you don't want to add an isSelected property to each data object you could keep a dictionary alongside that maps the objects to their selected state

Comment: @RHarris I updated my answer. Still not sure if this is what you are looking for though. If it isn't you want to add more details about your requirements so that we can help you find the appropriate solution?